# How to make a non-holo button with DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-theme

I am building an application to show a dynamic picture and a dialog with a button. The thumbnail of that picture is then used as the background of the button. However, if the picture is with black pattern, it turns out showing as "holo" and transparent to the background. This makes the button ugly. 

I am trying this on android 4.x. 

I have tried using different themes for the dialog, Theme.Dialog, Theme.Holo and Theme.Light but no luck.

My problems are

(1) how to make a non-holo button with DiaglogFragment(even on a holo theme view/activity).

(2) is this related to android versions? or machines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a selector with all the different states of a button and for each state you will need an image

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_curve" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_curve_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>  
</selector>
```

then set the background to the selector in your xml

Comment: Tried. but still no luck. The picture seems overlay the background, so still  holo. I tried use two machines,from two manufacturers, all android 4.0.4. One is okay, but the other is not. Is theme related to machines/os settings?